# NotificationService in android M

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

My application uses NotificationService which works fine on devices with up to Android L. When trying it on device with android M, service doesn't start. OnCreate is not fired at all.

Service is normally declared in AndroidManifest:

```
   <service android:name="com.abc.def.MyCustomService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Any ideas how to fix the issue?

Comment: Have you got implemented onBind()?